# Connection issue when trying to connect HBase in remote server using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I try to connect with HBase in a remote server using java. Below is my java code

```
String zookeeperHost = "myserverIP";
String tableName = "User";

Configuration hconfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hconfig.setInt("timeout", 1200);
hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",zookeeperHost);
hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
TableName tname = TableName.valueOf(tableName);

try {
    HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(hconfig);
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor(tname);
htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));
htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));
System.out.println( "Connecting..." );
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hconfig);
HBaseAdmin hbase_admin = (HBaseAdmin)connection.getAdmin();
System.out.println( "Creating Table..." );
hbase_admin.createTable( htable );
System.out.println("Done!");
```

but I keep getting this exception

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException:
>
> com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection >refused: no further information

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you check the hbase server is allowing incoming connections for the port that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes I can telnet for given port from my laptop. My server is a Google cloud VM instance. I have created firewall rules for zookeeper port and other required ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two reasons for below exception

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException

1. Remote VM hostname/IP is not accessible by client machine. In order to fix that, you need to update the inbound rules to allow port access. If in case of a VM host name, make sure you have added an entry in `/etc/hosts` to resolve the host name with IP address.
2. Second issue could be the HBase master is running. Make sure if HMaster service is running from your remote server.

Comment: when I hit jps it shows following => {{ 11216 HMaster
12018 Jps
4162 NodeManager
3943 SecondaryNameNode
11160 HQuorumPeer
11306 HRegionServer
3803 DataNode
4077 ResourceManager
3693 NameNode }} . So HMaster is running

Comment: hmm.. did you get the chance to check the logs once? And also try to run `hbase shell` and see if it works

Comment: yeah @Nishu Tayal. hbase shell is working.There is nothing in hbase master logs when I am trying to create a connection from my java code.

Comment: I can get HBase master UI also.

Comment: Have you added inbound rules in your vnet to allow the incoming connections?

Comment: when I add my remote server's hostname into my local host file, it worked :) Thank you very much @Nishu Tayal for the support

Answer (score 0):

Add below in 'hconfig'

```
 hconfig.set("hbase.master", hbaseConnectionIpAddr);
 hconfig.set("hbase.master.port", hbaseConnectionPortNum);
```

Comment: above properties are not really required to connect to HMaster

Comment: when I add remote server's hostname into my local host file, it worked. :) Thank you very much @Rushikesh Garadade for the support